# Can't stop or restart JBoss AS 4.2.3 as a service in Fedora

Tags: service, jboss, fedora

i have a little issue with a Jboss AS 4.2.3 . I'm developing an application in Seam so i'm using Jboss as server. In the client company they have a Jboss AS 4.2.3 installed on Fedora and configured as a service, so it starts automatically on boot machine with PostgreSQL. So, if i run chkconfig --list i can see Jboss here as a service.

But the problem is when i try to restart, stop or start this service (i have root permissions) using this command:

```
service jboss stop/restart
```

But i don't know what happens that looks like it doesn't find the Jboss AS instance that's running because i get this message:

```
JOBSS_CMD_START = cd /opt/java/jboss/bin; /opt/java/jboss/bin/run.sh -c default
No JBossas is currently running
```

But it's running because if i enter localhost:8080 on a browser it loads the Jboss page. The server admin of the company doesn't know also why the service can't restart or stop or start and only i know that he followed this tutorial to install and configure JBoss AS:

[thewiki4opentech.org/index.php/How_to_install_JBoss_AS_in_CentOS_/*RedHat*/_Fedora](http://thewiki4opentech.org/index.php/How_to_install_JBoss_AS_in_CentOS_/_RedHat_/_Fedora)

Also, i tried with

```
/etc/init.d/jboss stop
```

And i get the same output. If i use

```
/opt/java/jboss/bin/start.sh -c default
```

It tries to start a second instance of Jboss AS but it gives me errors because is trying to use the same ports as already started Jboss instance.

And it's difficult to me because i'm connecting remotely using Teamviewer and i want to deploy an EAR but i can't because i can't restart the service to extract the ear. So i wanna ask you for help if you know why the Jboss AS that's running can't be stopped or started using service jboss stop.

As aditional info, i'm using the config to access Jboss apps from other machines (using 0.0.0.0) and the server has a static IP. The config of my hosts file is this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
192.168.1.106 entertechserver.localdomain entertechserver
#::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Regards.

Comment: Why don't you just use the shutdown.sh script under $JBOSS_HOME/bin?

Comment: When i run 

`pidof jboss`

it doesn't give a PID, is empty.

Comment: @CoolBeans it gives me the same message `No JBossas is currently running` i don't know if the fact that it doesn't have a PID is normal or is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i think that i found the answer. The server admin copy the script run.sh to /etc/init.d/ but we saw that there's another script named jboss_init_redhat.sh that i think is optimized for redhat/fedora systems, so we used this script to copy to /etc/init.d/ and it works!! Now when i stop it gives me the next output:

```
JBOSS_CMD_START = cd /opt/java/jboss/bin; /opt/java/jboss/bin/run.sh -c default -b 0.0.0.0

waiting for processes to stop
```

Really i haven't seen the difference between both scripts yet but it will be intersting to take a look.

Regards.